# Connection to remote machine postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, postico

I am trying to connect to a VM ubuntu from my local computer. On the VM I have created a postgresql database. Then I followed all steps that I could find on several tutorial when it comes to allow access for remote connexion to the db:

- add `host all all  0.0.0.0/0  trust` to the pg_hba.conf file
- add `listen_addresses = '*'` to the postgresql.conf file
- remove the firewall by executing `sudo ufw allow 5432/tcp`
- restart postresql by executing `sudo systemctl restart postgresql`

By using the command `psql` and then `\c` gives `You are now connected to database "postgres" as user "postgres".`
I then create a password by executing `ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'password';`

Then I use postico to connect locally. I want to connect with this same default superuser `postgres` for testing. I use the VM ip address as host, db name is postgres user postgres, password is password and port 5432 as mentioned above.

After trying to connect for a while with the message `opening connection to server`, the result is:

```
could not connect to server: Operation timed out
    Is the server running on host "***.**.**.***" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Any help please? I did all steps I could find on many tutorials but still failing to connect.

Comment: From the virtual machine, can you connect with psql if you specify `-h 127.0.0.1`?  How about using the real IP address rather than 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Where are the VM and the machine you trying to connect from in relation to each other? What is OS and version of connecting machine? I don't understand this 'Then I use postico to connect locally. ', when you also say 'I use the VM ip address ...`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver there are my local computer mac OS and a remote Ubuntu virtual machine. I am trying to connect form my local computer to the remote machine where the database is stored..

Comment: @jjanes Yes I can connect with the command `psql -h 127.0.0.1`

Comment: So the firewall you created a rule for was on the remote Ubuntu machine, correct? Where is this Ubuntu machine running, AWS, Azure, Linode, somewhere else? To do `psql -h 127.0.0.1` on the virtual machine you ssh into it? To me it looks like there is another firewall between your Mac and the VM.